# Reset iOS emulator on each build

Tags: ios, xcode, emulation

Is there any way to setup the target/scheme to make it reset iOS emulator on every build?

I'm using XCode 6.1.

1. First try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966288/how-to-automatically-reset-iphone-simulator-on-build) didn't work... why?

[image: Pre script]

Thanks

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966288/how-to-automatically-reset-iphone-simulator-on-build

Comment: I'm trying that solution but is not working